# Sqlite query reports SQLITE_CORRUPT

Tags: sqlite

I have an embedded system running with a RTOS and is using C language.

I am using Sqlite to maintain a file(let's call it sqlLiteFile.db) on a File System residing on a NAND. The Sqlite version is 3.8.5

Earlier, I was creating a new database for this file every time the system comes up. So, it was a volatile file. I had no issues at that time.

However, now I made the sqlLiteFile.db to be persistent. So, every time system reboots, it opens the same file and starts writing. This works fine for some time, and survives few reboots. But, after a while, the Sqlite query starts reporting SQLITE_CORRUPT error. However, the write operation to sqlite still works fine, it is the query which starts reporting error. I can see the write operation successful, using a debugger. Also, the size of the file in the file system keeps increasing.

When I download the file and use Sqlite browser, I can not open the file anymore. When I use some other tool to convert the sqlLiteFile.db to sqlLiteFile.txt, I can see an error at the bottom: /**** ERROR: (11) database disk image is malformed *****/

Any suggestions on how to prevent this corruption would be helpful.

Edit:
Further I did try doing clean shutdowns which closes the database using  sqlite3_close() prior to rebooting. This time the database survived a little longer through reboots, but it got corrupted again eventually. So, it seems it is more then just about closing the database before exiting the application. Probably the size?

Update:
The system reboots(and re-opening/closing the sqlite database) doesn't cause corruption, but it happens after the database size reaches a certain amount(~55 Kb)

Comment: Are you calling `sqlite3_close()` before shutting down?

Comment: I am not, because most of the times it is an unexpected shutdown on my system.

Comment: See http://www.sqlite.org/howtocorrupt.html; it's likely that that file system does not implement fsync() correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It did seem that fsync() was doing something to the sqlite database. Taking out fsync() functionality didn't cause sqlite corruption. Also, I was opening and reading the database while downloading and at the same time sqlite database was written. Both these factor or fsync() alone was causing file system corruption. I still need to figure out a better way to perform fysnc(), but now I know exactly what was causing the corruption.